# Не могу обратиться к свойствам JSON-объекта в шаблонизаторе EJS

Tags: javascript, json, ejs

Странная ситуация встречается уже второй раз. Допустим, имеется массив объектов такого плана:

```
var a = [
    { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2 },
    { 'a' : 3, 'b' : 4 },
    { 'a' : 5, 'b' : 4 }
];
```

На деле объекты огромные. Вот я хочу, например, отфильтровать массив, взяв только объекты с b = 4:

```
<% var b = a.filter( function( filtered ) { return filtered.b === 4; }); %>
```

Получаю массив объектов b без нулевого объекта массива a:

```
[
    { 'a' : 3, 'b' : 4 },
    { 'a' : 5, 'b' : 4 }
];
```

И здесь какая-то аномалия. При прохождении циклом по элементам массива, я не могу получить свойства объектов:

```
<% for( index in b ) { %>
    <%- b[ index ].b %>
<% } %>
```

Должен получить 4, но получаю пустоту. b[ index ].b имеет тип undefined, однако объект b[ index ] имеет тип object. Пытаюсь пройти массив другими способами:

```
<% b.forEach( function( bData ) { %>
    <%- bData.b %>
<% }); %>
```

Тоже самое. Теперь пытаюсь через .each - ejs ругается, нет такой функции. Может так:

```
<%
var bLenght = b.length;
for( var i = 0; i < bLenght; b++ ) {
%>
    <%- b[i].b %>
<%
}
%>
```

Тоже никак.

Почему так происходит в шаблонизаторе ejs ? Как я могу "докопаться" до свойств объектов?

---

UPDATE

О как интересно получается..

```
<%- JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( b ) ).b %>
```

Получаю 4. Ваши комментарии?

Comment: в последнем варианте у вас ошибка тут: `var bLenght` и `i < bLength`

Comment: так выведите весь объект и посмотрите что это за объект

Comment: @Grundy да, он указан в третьем "листинге" ("Получаю массив объектов b без нулевого объекта массива a")